# Where can I find US ARTCC sector boundary coordinates?

Tags: air-traffic-control, usa, airspace

For an academic purpose, I would like to map US airspace using GIS tools with coordinates. I found the airspace boundary coordinates from the eNASR, but no luck with the sector boundaries.

Any information you can provide me would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The center boundaries are available online but sector boundaries are hard to come by. I expect it's because they change often and are really not all that useful to pilots.

Comment: Users of virtual ATC networks will probably have the answer ([VATSIM](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/VATSIM), [IVAO](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Virtual_Aviation_Organisation)) as they need to define their sectors as well.

Answer (score 1):

For any ARTCC you can contact their Airspace and Procedures office. Be polite, and specific. They will have that information. It should be publicly available. The cities for the lower 48 where ARTCCs are (associated city name and actual location)

Albuquerque (NE side of town) 505-856-4500

Atlanta (Hampton GA you should hear it when the speedway fires up) 770-210-7600

Boston (Nashua NH) 603-879-6633

Chicago (Aurora IL) 630-906-8200

Cleveland (Oberlin OH) 440-774-0300

Denver (Longmont, my facility, tell 'em CD from training sent ya) 303-651-4100

Fort Worth (north side of DFW airport) 866-835-5322

Houston (just south of airport) 281-230-5600

Indianapolis (at the airport) 317-247-2234

Jacksonville (Hillyard FL) 904-845-1500

Kansas City (Olathe) 913-254-8400

Los Angeles (Palmdale) 510-745-3000

Memphis (NE of airport) 901-368-8101

Miami (North Miami in a warehouse district...) 305-716-1500

Minneapolis (Farmington MN) 651-463-5514

New York (Ronkonkoma) 631-468-1001

Oakland (Fremont) 510-745-3000

Salt Lake City (airport) 801-575-2400

Seattle (Everett WA) 866-835-5322

Washington DC (Leesburg VA)703-377-3401

These numbers are for their respective switchboards, select "Airspace and Procedures" from the menu.